# Foldering files in drawable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I want to put several drawable resource file in a package with specific name in the drawable directory but I don't know how to do that.

I tried to do clean code stuff but I don't know how to manage the files in drawable. If I can't do that please tell me what is the best way to do it.

Comment: That's not really supported by Android, sorry. You cannot readily have package directories, or any sort of directories, inside of resource directories.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I support @CommonsWare comment.

> You can use the Resource Manager to import image resources into your
> project. For a list of supported image types, see Image support.

[image: Resource Manager]

Drag your images directly onto the Resource Manager window in Android Studio.

[Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/supported-formats?hl=en#image-formats)